# Error with Eclips, Error in an XML file: aborting build

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Hey I have a problem with my Eclips code 
It says Error in an XML file: aborting build. 
I create an xml folder in the res folder with a file in 
it named accessoryfilter.xml

```
package HelloWorld.adk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
<activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.Launcher" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name"android.hadware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hadware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
android:resource="@xml/accessoryfilter" />
</activity>

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing Java code with content of the manifest file. Don't do that.

Comment: I seriously hope this isn't the problem... let us pray that it is just a disastrous typo, haha

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all... I have absolutely no idea what is up with the mixture of Java and XML in your post. Please do something to fix that.
2. You should be putting your XML information in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file... not in `res/xml`. Your question doesn't mention anything about the android manifest, so I'm not sure whether or not this is the problem.
3. There are a number of typos in the code that you have posted. For example, `portait` should be `portrait`, `Launcher` should be `LAUNCHER`, `hadware` should be `hardware`.

   In other words, you really need to update your post before we can help you out. Put yourself in our shoes and ask yourself "would I understand what this code represents if I looked at it for the first time?" before you post again.

Comment: ok I changed that but there is the same Error it is in my src folder my manifestfolder seams to be ok and my book told me to crate a folder in res called xml with a folder called accessory_filter.xml with that code : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-accessory manufacturer="Manufacturer" model="Model" version="Version" />
</resources>

Comment: Do you see the content of your post right now? It is barely readable. Please fix it with proper formatting and add all relevant information to the post so that people can help.